# How Can I Enhance CSS Value Regularly?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, frontend, dom-events

it is My button.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button
```

and it is script..

```
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById("x").style.marginLeft = +35 ;
}
```

when I push the Button, element x moving but the second push is not working.

Comment: 35 what? Units....You are setting marginLeft to 35.... you are not adding 35 to the value

Comment: it is just a random number

Comment: You should use units.... that is what I was saying.

Comment: no, not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just setting the marginLeft to the number 35. It is not adding 35 to the margin. marginLeft also needs a unit. So you need to say whatever the unit is.

So you need to read the current value, remove the units, and add the new value, and then set the new value.

```js
function myFunction(){
 var elem = document.getElementById("x");
 var current = Number(elem.style.marginLeft.replace("px", ''));
 elem.style.marginLeft = (current + 35) + "px" ;
}
```

```css
#x {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button id="x" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: With `parseInt` you won't need to strip `px` from the string. But hey, now we're just nitpicking ;).

Comment: @EmielZuurbier That assumes it is always a whole number... I assumed it could be any number. But yes parseInt would be fine.

Comment: Can I define max range? because it is moving to infinite.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function myFunction(){
 let el = document.getElementById("x");
 el.style.marginLeft = Number(el.style.marginLeft.replace("px", "")) + 35 + "px" ;
}
```

Comment: This works because you increment the marginLeft property by 35. It's basically like saying to your computer: "get the marginLeft value of an element with an id of 'X' and add 35 to it."

Comment: Add 35 of *what*? You're on the right track.

Comment: my bad, i have been using react too much. add "px" to the end.